# vercel "npm install" exited with 1

Tags: reactjs, github, next.js, sanity

Help! I am trying to deploy a (Next js) project to vercel but keep getting this error.

I have already reinstalled all dependencies several times, but the error still shows.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: next-sanity-image@5.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @sanity/client@4.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@sanity/client
npm ERR!   @sanity/client@"^4.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @sanity/client@"^3.0.0" from next-sanity-image@5.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/next-sanity-image
npm ERR!   next-sanity-image@"^5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @sanity/client@3.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@sanity/client
npm ERR!   peer @sanity/client@"^3.0.0" from next-sanity-image@5.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/next-sanity-image
npm ERR!     next-sanity-image@"^5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /vercel/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-01-04T11_51_59_052Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

I have tried every available command to resolve dependencies conflict.

Comment: Can you give us more information? Where are you getting this error? You say during deployment and have added a GitHub tag to the question. Does that mean you get this error in a GitHub Actions Workflow for example? What version of Node are you running on? Etc.

Comment: This is indicative of version conflicts between dependencies either in your project or in your project's dependencies. It might be worth sharing your package.json and/or changing version numbers for packages: `next-sanity-image`, `sanity/client`, or packages that depend on these packages.

Comment: Ok actually I get the error on vercel when I try to deploy the projects.
Here is my git repo link: https://github.com/Taribi-Isaac/next-ecommerce.git

Comment: The node version I have on my machine is v18.12.1.